# How to properly parse nested Structure in ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am working on a C SDK, where I need to retrieve results from a nested `struct`. I dont have a good way to describe it, but here goes

It begins with a callback function, where I need to map a value returned (`lCommand`) to its corresponded function.

If `lCommand == 0x2800`, the corresponded struct is `NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT` and I need to create an object of it and then referenced the memory address. Inside `NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT`, there is another struct `NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO` and I need to retrieve a variable called `sLicense`

```
char sLicense[16];
```

I am expecting results like `ABC 123`, but instead it gives a `bytes` value, `b'\xf4\xfd\x14?#\xdb\x19?\x9c\xc4 >%\x06\x81='`.

You can download the sdk [here](https://mega.nz/#!YFMGDaLI!ImqF616PesZyE3dcjCbhEk2TUa0KrXXZLsYSK7Q8TIQ) and search for this method: `NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31`

**Code**

```
class NET_DVR_ALARMER(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("byUserIDValid", c_byte)
    ]

class NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("byPlateType", c_byte),
        ("byColor", c_byte),
        ("byBright", c_byte),
        ("byLicenseLen", c_byte),
        ("byEntireBelieve", c_byte), # accuracy
        ("byRegion", c_byte),
        ("byCountry", c_byte),
        ("byRes", c_byte*24),
        ("dwXmlLen", c_ulong),
        ("sLicense", c_char*16),
        ("byBelieve", c_char*16) # accuracy of every recognizing character
    ]

class NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("dwSize", c_ulong),
        ("byResultType", c_byte),
        ("byChanIndex", c_byte),
        ("wAlarmRecordID", c_ushort),
        ("dwRelativeTime", c_ulong),
        ("byAbsTime", c_byte*32),
        ("byTrafficLight", c_byte),
        ("byPicNum", c_byte),
        ("byDriveChan", c_byte),
        ("byVehicleType", c_byte),
        ("byRes3", c_byte*8),
        ("struPlateInfo", NET_DVR_PLATE_INFO)
    ]

def MsgCallback(lCommand, pAlarmer, pAlarmInfo, dwBufLen, pUser):
    messageType = str(hex(lCommand))
    if messageType == "0x2800":
        struPlateResult = NET_DVR_PLATE_RESULT()
        memmove(pointer(struPlateResult), pAlarmInfo, sizeof(struPlateResult))

        struPlateInfo = struPlateResult.struPlateInfo
        print("Accuracy: {}".format(struPlateInfo.byEntireBelieve))
        print("License Plate: {}".format(struPlateInfo.sLicense))
        print("License Plate Length: {}".format(struPlateInfo.byLicenseLen))
    return True

def setDVRMsgCallback(sdk):
    callback_t = CFUNCTYPE(c_bool, c_long, POINTER(NET_DVR_ALARMER), c_void_p, c_ulong, c_void_p)
    sdk.NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31.restype = c_bool
    if sdk.NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31(callback_t(MsgCallback)):
        print("Init callback event")
    else:
        print("Unable to init NET_DVR_SetDVRMessageCallBack_V31")
        print(sdk.NET_DVR_GetLastError())

if __main__:
    sdk = SDK(ip="192.168.0.246", port="8000")

    setupSuccess = False
    while not setupSuccess:
        setDVRMsgCallback(sdk) # setup callback methods
        sleep(1)               # give device some time to adapt new requests
        setupSuccess = NET_DVR_SetupAlarmChan_V41(sdk, lUserID) # initiate alarm
        sleep(0.5)

    sleep(1000)

    sdk.logout(lUserID)
    sdk.cleanup()
```

Comment: Where do you register your callback (*MsgCallback*)? I don't see any code that tells the *SDK* something about it.

Comment: @CristiFati Sorry I forgot to include that part of the snippet. Post updated. And FYI, I was following this [tutorial](https://coolview.github.io/2018/09/26/Python%20%E8%B0%83%E7%94%A8%E6%B5%B7%E5%BA%B7%20SDK/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through the SDK documentation, I believe the SDK is written in Windows environment.

According to [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int),

> c_int represents the C signed int datatype. The constructor accepts an optional integer initializer; no overflow checking is done. On platforms where sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) it is an alias to c_long.

I noticed some of the parameters inside the struct definitions are declared type `c_ulong` for what's declared as `DWORD` in the SDK. You might want to validate if the field types are being supplied correctly in your development platform.

Other than that make sure you declare full struct definitions for all the structs involved. Otherwise you will get incorrect results or even segmentation faults.

Comment: Thanks! I tested and changing the variable types work!